# Bootstrap 3 Collapsible Menu is not Animating Slide in/out

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get a navbar fixed at the top of my page to animate (slide in/out) when it appears and reappears. I'd also like it to collapse when viewed on mobile devices.

I'm just starting with bootstrap and most of the code is from a tutorial, including the button which appears when the screen and displays a drop down.

When I call collapse('toggle') there isn't any animation, even though to docs seem to suggest there is supposed to be an animation (http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse talks about the time between when it starts hiding and is hidden)

I'm using flat ui, though removing it doesn't solve the problem. I also tried removing everything in the button besides the navbar-brand link; it still doesn't animate. I tried seeing if the panel-collapse or navbar-collapse classes would make it animate, also didn't work.

Is there a quick fix to this problem? Should I manually be coding this animation?

Here's the html/js code I'm using:

```
<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {

   $(document).click(function() {
     $("#lyla-nav").collapse('toggle')
   });
  });

</script>
<div id="lyla-nav" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top collapse nav-collapse">
  <div class="container">
    <button data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" class="navbar-toggle">
      <!--literally is making each line inside of the button--><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button><a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Welcome</a>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you mean to have `collapse nav-collapse` in the navbar div?  That's making the navbar not show and probably confusing the data target.  You shouldn't need your own script here.  See me example where I've moved the collapse and nav-collapse from the navbar div. http://jsbin.com/mukep/1/edit

Comment: I am trying to make the nav-bar not show initially and then slide in an out when the mouse is clicked (I'll have a different event trigger eventually). Something similar to the navbar here [link](http://andrevv.com/work/symbolism/). I'm not 100% sure how to data-target thing works, so that might be part of the problem.